# UitableViewCell not properly displaying accessories

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a friendslist view controller that allows the user to see pending friend requests. The isPending method is first used to see if a particular user has a pending friend request with the current user.

```
-(BOOL)isPending:(PFUser *)user
{
    for (PFUser *pending in self.Pending){
        if ([pending.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]){
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This method is called within cellForRowAtIndexPath method inside the TableViewController. THe problem that I am experiencing is that If I run the query inside the tableViewController users who are pending are properly displayed. When I moved the query to a singleton datasource class,  I have setup a delegate method that is called when data is returned from the query.

```
-(void)pendingFriendsQuarryDidFinishWithData{
    self.Pending = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataHolder.getPendingFriendsList];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Calling reloadData does not cause the checkmarks to appear next to the users names.

EDIT: Here is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath. It does not change with the singleton.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = user.username;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.email;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Treehouse.png"];

    if([self isPending:user]){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

What does change is how the data is obtained. Without the singleton here is the code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    /*
    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (self.currentUser != nil){
        PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
        PFQuery *pendingUser = [PFUser query];
        PFRelation *friendRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendRelation"];
        PFQuery *existingFriends = [friendRelation query];
        PFQuery *pendingFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
        userQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
        pendingFriends.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
        [pendingFriends whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
        [pendingFriends whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Pending"];
        [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId"doesNotMatchKey:@"toUser" inQuery:pendingFriends];
        [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:@"objectId" inQuery:existingFriends];
        [userQuery orderByAscending:@"username"];
        [userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                NSLog(@" Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo] );
            }else{
                NSLog(@"All Users Array Starts Here: %@", objects);
                self.allUsers = objects;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }];
        [pendingUser whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"toUser" inQuery:pendingFriends];
        [pendingUser orderByAscending:@"username"];
        [pendingUser findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }else{
                [self.Pending addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                NSLog(@"Pending Friends Array Stars here: %@", self.Pending);
            }
        }];
    }
    */
}
```

With singleton

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    dataHolder = [DataHolder sharedInstance];
    dataHolder.delegate = self;

    self.friends = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.allUsers = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.allUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataHolder.getAllUsersWithQuarry];
    self.Pending = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.Pending = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataHolder.getPendingFriendsListWithQuarry];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Now in Connection Editor");

}

-(void)allUsersQuarryDidFinishWithData{
    self.allUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataHolder.getAllUsers];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)pendingFriendsQuarryDidFinishWithData{
    self.Pending = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataHolder.getPendingFriendsList];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Please show your code for cellForRow both with the singlton and without.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? In Breakpoint on the pendingFriend finished and print out the contents of self.Pending. Then follow the breakpoint to cellForRow and check if isPending comes back true. My guess is one of your mutable arrays is empty when you think it should be full. May be a race condition. Make sure viewDidLoad gets called before the other calls

Comment: I setup an NSLog to log the array when its first created, when the delegate methods are called with additional data, inside the tableView CellForRowAtIndexPath method to see the arrays and also within isPending to see when the method is called. Im noticing that each method is called multiple times as data comes in and reloadData is called on the tableView. isPending method is being called when both arrays have data so it can work. The tableViewAccesories are not being displayed properly though.

Comment: I have found that instead of enumerating through self.pending array, enumerating through dataholder.getPendingFriendList solves the problem in the isPending method.

Answer (score 1):

Silly question, did you set the datasource of your tableviewcontroller to point to your singleton datasource?

```
tableview.datasource = [your singleton class instance]
```

and make sure that you step into it in the debugger.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have not set my datasource to anything. I have 2 different arrays that are needed for the isPending to work.I'm not sure how to setup the datasource in that case.

Comment: either you add those arrays inside of your singleton and/or pass them as parameters to your singleton.

Comment: I have arrays inside the tableViewController that act as the datasource (not set as so). They call the singleton to get the datasource and are then [self.tableViewArray ArrayWithArray:[[singleton shared instance]getdata];

Comment: I think you're complicating your code for no reason. try to step back and see how you structure your data. If you're using Storyboard to create your tableview most likely your datasource is already set to your UITableViewController subclass.